# How to eliminate items with the same last letter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to delete elements which have the same last letter. For example the following input has 
cA, bA and aA. All have A at the end. I want to keep only the first one.

aC and cC have the same C and I want to keep aC, the first one etc.

Input

```
arr = ["cA", "bA", "aA", "bB", "aC", "cC", "dD", "aD"]
```

desired out put

```
["cA", "bB", "aC", "dD"]
```

I tried this but it gives nil.

```
arr = ["cA", "bA", "aA", "bB", "aC", "cC", "dD", "aD"]
def deletesamesuffix(arr)
  arr.reject { |e| e.inculde? e[1] 
end

deletesamesuffix(arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
["cA", "bA", "aA", "bB", "aC", "cC", "dD", "aD"]
.group_by{|s| s[-1]}.values.map(&:first)
# => ["cA", "bB", "aC", "dD"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

**Code**

```
arr.map { |str| str[-1] }.uniq.map { |c| arr.find { |s| s[-1] == c } }
```

**Explanation**

```
a = arr.map { |str| str[-1] }
  #=> ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"]
b = a.uniq
  #=> ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
b.map { |c| arr.find { |s| s[-1] == c } }
  #=> ["cA", "bB", "aC", "dD"]
```